# How to check which rows has been generated error while import data from Excel file to the table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have an Excel file with 10,000 records. I want to import this file into a table in an Oracle database. But I found some error while importing the data.

How can I check which records has been generate as error while import?

Here is the code to import-

```
load data infile D:\WORKOUT\SD.csv
into table md.cus
field terminated by ','
trailing nullcods
( orderdate => orderdate,
  region => region,
  rep => rep,
  item => item,
  units => units,
  unitcost => unitcost,
  total => total);
```

Comment: are you using sqlloader for import ?

Comment: Can you pls share your import query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use External Tables for this case. 
Configure a .bad file.
So you can check your bad rows in it.

This maybe help you.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm